# what is a dependency for android.media.tv

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-tv

I try to move android TV app to Android studio. When I try to compile it, I had some import errors. I couldn't find the dependency that I can add to build.gradle to fix these problem. The list of the imports are:

```
import android.media.tv.TvContentRatingSystemInfo;
import android.media.tv.TvContract.WatchedPrograms;
import com.android.tv.tuner.data.nano.Track.AtscCaptionTrack;
import com.android.tv.tuner.data.nano.Track.AtscAudioTrack;
import com.android.tv.tuner.data.nano.Channel;
```

The build.gradle is :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
 compileSdkVersion 26
 buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

 defaultConfig {
     applicationId "com.android.tv"
     minSdkVersion 23
     targetSdkVersion 23
     versionCode 1
     versionName "1.0"

     ndk {
         moduleName "libtunertvinput_jni"
     }
 }
 sourceSets {
     main {
         res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/usbtuner-res']
         jni.srcDirs = []
     }
 }
 buildTypes {
     release {
         minifyEnabled false
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
     }
     debug {
         minifyEnabled false
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
     }
 }
}

dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 compile files('libs/exoplayer.jar')
 compile project(':common')
 compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:+'
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
 compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:+'
}
```

Comment: Can you post a simple project at github with that behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't import these because they have `@SystemApi` annotation. You can check [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/java/android/media/tv/TvContentRatingSystemInfo.java) for the source code of `TvContentRatingSystemInfo`. I have also checked `WatchedPrograms` and it also has `@SystemApi` annotation. I have not checked the other three.

You need to be system app to access these. As you can see [here](https://source.android.com/devices/tv/reference-tv-app), you need to push your app in the the `\system\` folder. You can find detailed information about AOSP build system [here](https://blog.jayway.com/2012/10/24/a-practical-approach-to-the-aosp-build-system/).

**Solution :**
Changing your `android.jar` to the .jar in this [github](https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api) should enable you to access system API. The reason is your standard `android.jar` doesn't have system API. So you need to get `framework.jar` (by `adb pull`) from emulator and combine it with `core.jar` then you can have new `android.jar` which contains system API (system methods and classes are available in the `framework.jar` from emulator).

Moreover, you should push your apk to `\system\priv-app\` folder to access some system API but I don't know why I can access system API without pushing my apk to `\system\priv-app\` when I use .jar from that github account.

I feel like I don't write quite clearly but at least now you have more understandings of what you're facing.

Answer (score 1):

`android.media.tv` and `com.android.tv` are part of Android SDK. So you don't need to include any additional libraries in **gradle.build** file.

Just make sure to:

[Update your SDK tools to version 24.0.0 or higher](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#GetTools)

and

[Update your SDK with Android 5.0 (API 21) or higher](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#GetTools)

Example,

```
 android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.tvapp"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
}
```

Comment: android platform version is : API 26    
androi SDK Tools : 26.0.02

but still it's not working

Comment: Did you try File > Invalidate Caches/Restart? Also, post your build.gradle files both app & module. @MRM

Answer (score 0):

use this in your dependencies  "com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.0.2"

and also use tool version  "26.0.1"

compiled SDK version 26.

Answer (score 0):

You can add dependencies in app level gradle.

```
compile 'com.google.android.libraries.tv:companionlibrary:0.1'
```